# Complex and large nested list of lists with varying lengths to dataframe in R

Tags: r, json, list, dataframe, nested

I'm accessing PUBGs API, and getting telemetry data from matches. This returns a rather large JSON-object, which is in turn parsed as a list of lists. I'd love to turn this into a data.frame for further handling, but I run into problems with the number of lists and varying lengths of each list. At best, I get 100k rows from a list of 12016 length, but not all of the list elements are included as columns.

**Code to get the data and parse it**

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
# Get telemetry from URL
telemetry <- httr::VERB(
  verb = "GET", url = "https://telemetry-cdn.playbattlegrounds.com/bluehole-pubg/steam/2020/06/28/13/52/8d51e4a6-b946-11ea-ac21-9e1c0fb3fbd4-telemetry.json",
  httr::add_headers(
    Accept = "application/json"
  )
)

#Parse telemetry data
telemetry_parsed <- content(telemetry, as="parsed") # Parse JSON-object
```

**Code that has gotten be the closest to what I want**

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

dt_list <- map(telemetry_parsed, as.data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(dt_list, fill = TRUE, idcol = T)
```

However, it's still a ways off. Looking at row 5, column "character" there is a list of coordinates that should've been different columns.

Any ideas? I've tried most of the answers to the "nested list of varying lengths to data.frame" answers.